# replace a line in a .profile using ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to insert a line at the end of my .profile using ansible. It should add to the end if the line is absent. I'm trying the following, but it does'nt do anything:

```
   - name: update profile
     lineinfile:
       dest: ~/.profile
       regexp: 'PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin'
       state: absent
       insertafter: EOF
       line: 'PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin'
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `state: present` if you want line to exist, and not sure why you want to use `regexp` in this case.
Also `EOF` is the default value for `insertafter`, so no need to define it.

```
 - name: update profile
   lineinfile:
     dest: ~/.profile
     state: present
     line: 'PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I want that line inserted if it is absent

Comment: state `present` means: add line if it is not there or leave it in place if it exists.